# RSA Archer Notification content

Tags: archer

I am trying to edit the content on standard notification. I want to split the body into two equal columns. When I try doing that in the HTML it always mess the CSS and automatically re-write it.

I am adding the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


.column-left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; 
}
.column-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; 
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Two Equal Columns</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column-left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
```

But as soon I hit "ok" it re-write it to this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">.c0 { font-family: 'Arial' } .c1 { margin: 0px 0px 14px; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold } .c2 { padding: 10px; background-color: #aaaaaa } .c3 { margin: 0px 0px 13px } .c4 { padding: 10px; background-color: #bbbbbb } </style>
  </head>
  <body class="c0">
    <div class="c1">Two Equal Columns</div>
    <div>
      <div class="c2">
        <div class="c1">Column 1</div>
        <p class="c3">text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="c4">
        <div class="c1">Column 2</div>
        <p class="c3">text </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Archer pretty much "dumbs" down the HTML formatting permitted in notifications. The best you can get away with is using tables instead of CSS to do columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want equal columns with any content, you can Choose the 'Body Layout' in the Notification as 'Two Column 50-50'.

That way, you can add any dynamic content within the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css grid

[Css Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) is good documentation

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column-left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```